# Conditional probability and uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

So, I've been having some trouble trying to solve the problem.

Let $U$ be a random variable that has a uniform distribution over $[0,2]$. What distribution has $U$ conditional on:

1. $U\leq 1$
2. $|U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2}$

Here's my attempt. For the first part of the problem I have this: $$P(U\leq u  \ |\ U\leq 1) = \frac{P( U \leq u \ \ , \ \ U \leq 1 )}{P(U\leq 1)}\text{,}$$ by definition. Now, finding $P(U \leq 1)$ is no hard task (it is simply equal to $\frac{1}{2})$, but I have no idea how I could find $P( U \leq u \ \ , \ \ U \leq 1 )$

For the second part of the problem, I've done the following: $$|U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} \geq U-1 \geq \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \geq 
U \geq \frac{3}{2}\\$$Therefore we have that $$P(|U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2}) = P(U \leq \frac{1}{2}) + P(U \geq \frac{3}{2}) \\ = 1/4 + \left(1-\frac{3}{4}\right) \\ = \frac{1}{2}$$

Now, again I have no idea how to compute $$P(U \leq u \ , \ |U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2}).$$

Comment: $$P(U \leq u, U \leq 1) = P(U \le u) \quad \forall\, u \le 1$$

Comment: Why is this the case, could you explain please  ? And what about when $u>1$ ?

Comment: $$U \le u \le 1$$

Comment: $$P(U\leq u , U\geq 1) = 0 \quad \forall\, u \le 1$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74867/discussion-between-gnu-supporter-and-skyris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$\forall\, u \in [0,1], P(U\leq u \mid U\leq 1) = \frac{P( U \leq u, U \leq 1 )}{P(U\leq 1)} = \frac{u/2}{1/2} = u$$  So the conditional distribution follows $\mathrm{Unif}([0,1])$.
2. $\forall\, u \in [0,2]$,
   \begin{align}
   P(U \leq u \ , \ |U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2}) &= P(U \le u, U \leq \frac{1}{2}) + P(U \le u, U \geq \frac{3}{2}) \\
   &= \min\{\frac{u}2, \frac14\} + P(\frac32 \le U \le u) \\
   &= \min\{\frac{u}2, \frac14\} + \max\{\frac{u}2-\frac34,0\} \\
   &= \begin{cases} \frac{u}2 & \quad u \in [0,\frac12] \\ \frac14 & \quad u \in [\frac12, \frac32] \\ \frac{u}2 - \frac34 & \quad u \in [\frac32, 2] \end{cases} \\
   P(U \leq u \mid \ |U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2}) &= \frac{P(U \leq u \ , \ |U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2})}{\underbrace{P(|U-1| \geq \frac{1}{2})}_{=1/2}} \\
   &= \begin{cases} u & \quad u \in [0,\frac12] \\ \frac12 & \quad u \in [\frac12, \frac32] \\ u - \frac32 & \quad u \in [\frac32, 2] \end{cases}
   \end{align}
   Differentiating with respect to $u$ on $(0,\frac12)$ and $(\frac32,2)$ gives constant density $1$.  This shows that the conditional distribution follows $\mathrm{Unif}([0,\frac12] \cup [\frac32,2])$.

Comment: Just a question though. $P(\frac{3}{2} \leq U \leq u) = P(U\leq u) - P(U \leq \frac{3}{2})$, now $P(U\leq u) = \frac{u}{2}$ and $P(U\leq \frac{3}{2}) = \frac{3}{4}$, Thus, shouldn't  $P(\frac{3}{2} \leq U \leq u) = \text{max}\left\{\frac{2u-3}{4},0\right\} $ ?

Comment: @Skyris My bad.  I overlooked the role of $2$ in $U \sim \mathrm{Unif}([0,2])$.  I'm going to fix it in 5 minutes.

Comment: @Skyris You're right.  I've already fixed that.